# SQL(ite) where clause with a colon (:) character

Tags: sql, escaping

I have a SQLite table column holding MAC addresses.

How do I write the SQL where clause for a string value including a colon ':' character? Surrounding it with quote characters doesn't work.

So far, I've been getting this error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ":66": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM PhoneStatus WHERE phoneDeviceId=00:66:4B:B2:7B:F5
```

Thanks!

Comment: Search the escape character of your dbms.. Also,  phoneDeviceId is of char type, enclose in single quotes. '00:66:4B:B2:7B:F5'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would seem to need single quotes for the string constant:

```
SELECT *
FROM PhoneStatus
WHERE phoneDeviceId = '00:66:4B:B2:7B:F5'
```

If the query is delimited by single quotes, then double them up or escape them somehow.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. neither does doubling nor escaping the quotes.

Comment: the problem was I was using a wrapper function which did not handle the string quoting correctly.
This worked:

SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PhoneStatus WHERE phoneDeviceId='00:66:4B:B2:7B:F5'");

thanks!